# After code changes, .Net website won't come up without deleting cache first

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a .Net website with C# code behind.

When I make coding changes to the website (on my local machine), and copy the files (.dll and .aspx files using ftp through Windows Explorer) to the server (hosted by GoDaddy) the site will sometimes not come up without clearing the browser cache first. It happens in IE, Firefox, and Chrome.

Does anyone know why this would happen and how to fix the issue?
(FYI - not sure if it matters, but the website has a SQL database and the site is http://www.fonyfacts.com/)
Thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you mean "not come up"? Do you get a 404 error? Another kind of error?

Comment: Looks completely normal. You should develop your website using local machine and deploy finished product. This way you won't have any problems like this.

Comment: Thanks System Down for the question. The browser just displays the loading animation forever, I believe the "timed out" message eventually came up.

Comment: @ABogus are you sure the server isn't just legitimately timing out? Try disabling your browsers cache and see if you can force it to time out still.

Comment: Thanks Stanislav and Snuffleupagus!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as you upload a new DLL your website will recycle and can take anything from a few seconds to much more to get going again - this is normal. This will also happen when some other files are changed too, such as the web.config. Like Stanislav says; build local and only upload when you're ready to run it.